# Can't get full result when joining the same table several times

Tags: actionscript-3, sqlite, air

I have this SQL code:

```
SELECT t1.offname, t2.offname, t3.offname, t4.offname, t5.offname, t6.offname, t7.offname
FROM AS_ADDROBJ_29 t1
LEFT JOIN AS_ADDROBJ_29 t2 ON t1.parentguid = t2.aoguid AND t1.parentguid NOT NULL
LEFT JOIN AS_ADDROBJ_29 t3 ON t2.parentguid = t3.aoguid AND t2.parentguid NOT NULL
LEFT JOIN AS_ADDROBJ_29 t4 ON t3.parentguid = t4.aoguid AND t3.parentguid NOT NULL
LEFT JOIN AS_ADDROBJ_29 t5 ON t4.parentguid = t5.aoguid AND t4.parentguid NOT NULL
LEFT JOIN AS_ADDROBJ_29 t6 ON t5.parentguid = t6.aoguid AND t5.parentguid NOT NULL
LEFT JOIN AS_ADDROBJ_29 t7 ON t6.parentguid = t7.aoguid AND t6.parentguid NOT NULL
WHERE t1.offname LIKE "smth%"
```

When I execute this with `SQLiteManager`, it returns 7 columns with some of columns equals to null.
But AIR returns me only last `t7` table result and other results are omitted. Different `SQLColumnNameStyle-s` not change the situation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with joining the same table - in result you get lots of columns with same names. AIR sqlite engine can't handle it properly, but there a simple hack: you just should name all columns with different string names. Like this:

```
SELECT t1.offname AS 'OFFNAME1', t2.offname AS 'OFFNAME2', t3.offname AS 'OFFNAME3', 
t4.offname AS 'OFFNAME4', t5.offname AS 'OFFNAME5', t6.offname AS 'OFFNAME6',
t7.offname AS 'OFFNAME7'
FROM AS_ADDROBJ_29 t1
LEFT JOIN AS_ADDROBJ_29 t2 ON t1.parentguid = t2.aoguid AND t1.parentguid NOT NULL
LEFT JOIN AS_ADDROBJ_29 t3 ON t2.parentguid = t3.aoguid AND t2.parentguid NOT NULL
LEFT JOIN AS_ADDROBJ_29 t4 ON t3.parentguid = t4.aoguid AND t3.parentguid NOT NULL
LEFT JOIN AS_ADDROBJ_29 t5 ON t4.parentguid = t5.aoguid AND t4.parentguid NOT NULL
LEFT JOIN AS_ADDROBJ_29 t6 ON t5.parentguid = t6.aoguid AND t5.parentguid NOT NULL
LEFT JOIN AS_ADDROBJ_29 t7 ON t6.parentguid = t7.aoguid AND t6.parentguid NOT NULL
WHERE t1.offname LIKE "smth%"
```

Now in SQLResult.data you will have object with 7 "OFFNAME#" keys and all values. Some of values will be equled to null.